# (PHP) API to 'Like' an Youtube Video?

Tags: php, youtube-api

> There is an one form on my website, which contains an text field to
>   get the 'youtube Video URL' from user. after submitting this URL, the
>   video found by that URL must get one like by that user(cosnider user
>   already logged-in to youtube account).
>   so my question is, where did i
>   find the php API for this?

Answer (score 1):

Check this doc out (it described like/dislike procedure)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate

In short, you should produce specific POST query (i.e. with CURL)

Comment: Thanks @Marinin Tim i think this will help me, will try and late you know if worked perfectly(as am not done curl programming in PHP :(